# How can I check the correctness of email end?

Tags: python, django

I need to check if there's a point in email after `"@"`.

```
if not email.endswith('.com'):
    args['reg_error'] = "Email is incorrect!"
```

I need to do something like this, but with any end which has point after `"@"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Django already checks with the email validtor if there is a point after the `@`.

Comment: Try `'.' in email[email.index('@'):]`

Comment: It might be better to simply use the `EmailValidator`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.EmailValidator

Comment: A valid email address does not need to have a dot after the @.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It must, but something goes wrong with it

Comment: @FunCreator: did you call `.full_clean()` on your model? Django by default does not validate field content when it saves that to the database, you need to explicitly call cleaning methods to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Arkistarvh Kltzuonstev!

I needed to write this:

```
if not '.' in email[email.index('@'):]:
    do something...
```